# If two Lie algebras have the same structure constants, are they isomorphic?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, vector-space-isomorphism

Denote the lie-algebra of $SU(2)$ by $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and that of $SO(3)$ by $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Is the fact that both $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ have the same structure constants enough to ensure that they are isomorphic? 
I.e if  $T_{\alpha},T_{\beta}$ are two generators in either: 
$$ [T_{\alpha},T_{\beta}] = \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}^{\gamma}T_{\gamma}$$

I can see that there's an argument that they are homomorphic.If they both have the same adjoint representation (same structure constants) then there is an isomorphism between the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. The adjoint representation of any lie algebra is a homomorphism (but *not* an isomorphism?) on that lie algebra.

So, since the composition of a homomorphism is itself a homomorphism (and being a homomorphism is a necessary condition to being an isomorphism) - if the structure constants are equal, then $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ are homomorphic.

Is there an extra ingredient I need to prove the isomoprhism - and am I roughly along the right lines?

Comment: The same structure constants with respect to the *same* basis means, the Lie algebras are equal, and hence isomorphic. Otherwise you need to show more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ be two Lie algebras with the same dimension $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ be basis of $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ respectively. Suppose that there are numbers $\epsilon_{ij}^k$ such that$$(\forall i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):[e_i,e_j]=\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_{ij}^ke_k\text{ and }[f_i,f_j]=\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_{ij}^kf_k.$$I suppose that this is what you mean when you assert that $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ “have the same structure constants”. If so, then, yes, $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ are isomorphic. You just take the (only) linear map $\psi\colon\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak h$ such that$$(\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):\psi(e_i)=f_i.$$Then $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: That is what I meant exactly - but I'm confused as to why that map is necessarily linear - or why I am necessarily sure I can construct such a map? Is it necessarily true that given $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ have the same dimension that this is possible?

Comment: @thesundayscientist Yes. This is a basic Linear Algebra fact: if $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of a vector space $E$ and if $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$ are elements of a vector space $F$, then there is one and only one linear map $L\colon E\longrightarrow F$ such that$$(\forall j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):L(e_j)=f_j.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Hi. I don't understand why we can assume $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ have the same dimension. Moreover, why can we assume that $$[e_i,e_j]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}e_{ij}^{k}e_k$$ and $$[f_i,f_j]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}e_{ij}^{k}f_k$$ where $\{e_{ij}^k\}_k$ are the structure constants. The way I see it, we can only assume that elements in the set $\{e_{ij}^k\}_k$ are both found as constant terms when expressing the lie bracket of any two basis vectors in $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$. Pardon my ignorance, I am not sure if my background on group theory and linear algebra is sufficient.

Comment: If the don't have the same dimension, then it doesn't make sense to assert that they have the same structure constants. The structure constants are a set of $n^3$ numbers and so $n$ becomes totally determined by them.

Comment: Okay I now understand why the equal dimension, but what about the structure constants.. Why can we assume that the structure constants used to express $[e_i,e_j]$ as a linear combination of elements in $\{e_i\}_i$ be the same as the structure constants used to express $[f_i, f_j]$ as linear combination of elements in $\{f_j\}_j$?

Comment: Asserting that two Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ have the same structure constants means that *there are* bases $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ and $\{h_1,\ldots,h_n\}$ of $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ respectively such that, if$$[g_i,g_j]=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ij}^kg_k\text{ and }[h_i,h_j]=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ij}^kh_k,$$then$$(\forall i,j,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):a_{ij}^k=b_{ij}^k.$$

Comment: There one exercise in Wildon's book  : Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be lie Algebras over a field $F$ . Show that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there is a basis $B_1$ of $L_1$ and $B_2$ of $L_2$ such that structure constants with respect to these bases are equal.  My Question is why there exists such a basis , I think it works for any basis. We can take any two basis and take any isomorphism between them that gives same structure constants . Can someone please clarify?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Is the convse of the statement which you had proved is true?

Comment: @Spectrum Of course.

Comment: There one exercise in Wildon's book : Let L1
 and L2
 be lie Algebras over a field F
 . Show that L1
 and L2
 are isomorphic if and only if there is a basis B1
 of L1
 and B2
 of L2
 such that structure constants with respect to these bases are equal. My Question is why there exists such a basis , I think it works for any basis. @José Carlos Santos We can take any two basis and take any isomorphism between them that gives same structure constants .  Can you please clarifyJosé Carlos Santos.

Comment: @Spectrum We **cannot** take any two bases. We take *some* basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $\mathfrak g$ and then, if $\psi\colon\mathfrak g\longrightarrow\mathfrak h$ is the isomorphism, we take the basis $\bigl\{\psi(e_1),\ldots,\psi(e_n)\bigr\}$ of $\mathfrak h$.

Comment: Thank you here is the significance of the  word "some" .

Comment: @Spectrum I have no idea about what that means.